# php parsing complex xml elements into order

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to write a php script which looks at an existing XML log and then print this information to the screen.
I been looking at simplexml_load_file() and other methods but I am stuck on one bit.
I want to show all information from the elements in order of what they appear in the xml file.
I know how to extract values and attributes but what I don't know is how to loop through test and detect 
 and print them in the order as shown below (i.e. 45,46,47,48,49,50.
I cannot change the xml structure as it out of my control.

What is the best approach for doing this?

Thanks

```
  <xml>
      <test name="test1">
        <time date="29/09/2014" />
        <message line="45" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 1</description>
        </message>
        <message line="46" type="TEST">
          <description>Example 2</description>
        </message>
        <verification line="47">
          <result type="pass" file="abc.py">
              <description>button was available</description>
              <description type="DETAILED"></description>
          </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="48" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 3</description>
        </message>
        <verification line="49">
          <result type="pass" file="abc.py">
              <description>button available</description>
              <description type="DETAILED"></description>
          </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="50" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 4</description>
        </message>
      </test>
  </xml>
```

Example output:

```
Test: test1
Date: 29/09/2014
Message - 45 - Log - Description: Example 1
Message - 46 - TEST - Description: Example 2
Verification - 47 - result=pass - button was available - DETAILED - file=abc.py
Message - 48 - Log - Description: Example 3
Verification - 49 - result=pass - button available - DETAILED - file=abc.py
Message - 50 - Log - Description: Example 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retain the order you could try an xpath expression that matches both Message and Verification.

Try this `$nodes = $xmlObj->xpath('test/*');`

Then you can iterate the result like this:

```
foreach ($nodes as $nodeType => $node) {
    //you can get node name with $node->getName()
    //node attributes with $node->attributes
    //and iterate node children with foreach($node->children() as $childNode)
}
```

Comment: This works as wanted, thank you very much. See my answer for full code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to transform you xml file into an array and then get your data:keys and values from the array:

```
<?php
$xml='<xml>
      <test name="test1">
        <time date="29/09/2014" />
        <message line="45" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 1</description>
        </message>
        <message line="46" type="TEST">
          <description>Example 2</description>
        </message>
        <verification line="47">
          <result type="pass" file="abc.py">
              <description>button was available</description>
              <description type="DETAILED"></description>
          </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="48" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 3</description>
        </message>
        <verification line="49">
          <result type="pass" file="abc.py">
              <description>button available</description>
              <description type="DETAILED"></description>
          </result>
        </verification>
        <message line="50" type="LOG">
          <description>Example 4</description>
        </message>
      </test>
  </xml>';
function xml_to_array($input, $callback = null, $recurse = false) {
                    $data = ((!$recurse) && is_string($input))? simplexml_load_string($input, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA): $input;
                    if ($data instanceof SimpleXMLElement) $data = (array) $data;
                    if (is_array($data)) foreach ($data as &$item) $item = xml_to_array($item, $callback, true);
                    return (!is_array($data) && is_callable($callback))? call_user_func($callback, $data): $data;
            } 


$xml=xml_to_array($xml);//transform you xml file to an array

function get_array_values($xml){ //search for all values in the required array
 foreach($xml as $key => $value) { 
    if(is_array($value)){
      get_array_values($value);
    }else{print $key." : ".$value."\n";}
 }
}
get_array_values($xml);
?>
```

#### Output:

```
name : test1
date : 29/09/2014
line : 45
type : LOG
description : Example 1
line : 46
type : TEST
description : Example 2
line : 48
type : LOG
description : Example 3
line : 50
type : LOG
description : Example 4
line : 47
type : pass
file : abc.py
0 : button was available
type : DETAILED
line : 49
type : pass
file : abc.py
0 : button available
type : DETAILED
```

Comment: The issue with that is the Message and Verification will get out of order. I need to display the Message and Verification in order which is seen in the XML file. other than lines, how can I tell where the Verification appears in the Messages. (lines No are examples and will not be in order). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to montexristos I have now got my answer. Below is the full code I needed.

```
 <?php
 $xmlObj= simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
 $nodes = $xmlObj->xpath('test/*');
 print "Test: ".$xmlObj->test['name']."<br>";

 foreach ($nodes as $nodeType => $node) {
     $name = $node->getName();
     if ($name == "time"){
         print "Date: ".$node['date']."<br>";
     }else if ($name == "message"){
         print "Message - ".$node['line']." - ".$node['type']." - Description: ".$node->description."<br>";
     }else if ($name == "verification"){
         print "Verification - ".$node['line']." - result=".$node->result['type']." - ".$node->result->description." - ".$node->result->description[1]['type']." - ".$node->result['file']."<br>";
     }
 }
 ?>
```